# What would be a good way to order by custom property in a django models query set?

Tags: python, django, sorting, sql-order-by, django-queryset

I have a custom property in my models, and I would like to order_by using that property:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices=REPORT_STATUS)

    @property
    def risk_rating(self):
        # Calculate risk rating here
        return risk_rating
```

I would like to do

```
reports = Report.objects.all().order_by('-risk_rating')
```

but of course it returns with a mysql error regarding the non-existent column. I would prefer not to recurse over calling this property in a sorting algorithm using python, but that is the only way I think I can get this to work.

```
reports = sorted(Report.objects.all(), key=lambda t: t.risk_rating)
```

Could I perhaps do better than that?

Comment: Why can't you push the calculation down to the db?  Or calculate the value and save it in the db ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the ORM uses the database to order and cannot operate on a python value.

You can...

1. Calculate at database level via django's `extra`
2. Calculate the data and set it in a new column upon model save, then order by that.
3. Use python sorting

Comment: I think I might take the second approach, and cache the risk_rating value in a new column each time the report gets published or updated. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the `lambda` with `operator.itemgetter`

```
import operator
reports = sorted(Report.objects.all(), key=itemgetter(risk_rating))
```

but I'm not sure if that's "better", perhaps you could explain how you would like the query improved?